# Why can the same events of a PatternStream be sent to both the PatternSelectFunction and the PatternTimeoutFunction?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-cep

I have to collect 3 events in 3 kafka sourced streams having the same correlationId in a given time, and be able to collect all or part of these events if they arrive late.

I used a union on the 3 DataStream and a CEP pattern. But I notice that **events that match well with the pattern and are therefore collected in the select function are also sent in the timeout function once the timeout is reached**.

I do not know what I did wrong in my example, or what I did not understand, but I was expecting that the events that are positively matching are not also in timeout.

I get the impression that disjoint time snapshots are stored.

I'am using the 1.3.0 Flink version.

Thank you for your help.

The console output, where we can see that 2 of the 3 correlated events are selected and timeouted:

Matching events:
Key---0b3c116e-0703-43cb-8b3e-54b0b5e93948
Key---f969dd4d-47ff-445c-9182-0f95a569febb
Key---2ecbb89d-1463-4669-a657-555f73b6fb1d

Timed out events:

First call to the timeout function:
Key---f969dd4d-47ff-445c-9182-0f95a569febb
Key---0b3c116e-0703-43cb-8b3e-54b0b5e93948
Second call:
Key---f969dd4d-47ff-445c-9182-0f95a569febb

```
11:01:44,677 INFO  com.bnpp.pe.cep.Main                                          - Matching events:
11:01:44,678 INFO  com.bnpp.pe.cep.Main                                          - SctRequestProcessStep2Event(super=SctRequestEvent(correlationId=cId---a14a4e23-56c5-4242-9c43-d465d2b84454, key=Key---0b3c116e-0703-43cb-8b3e-54b0b5e93948, debtorIban=BE42063929068055, creditorIban=BE42063929068056, amount=100.0, communication=test), succeeded=false)
11:01:44,678 INFO  com.bnpp.pe.cep.Main                                          - SctRequestProcessStep1Event(super=SctRequestEvent(correlationId=cId---a14a4e23-56c5-4242-9c43-d465d2b84454, key=Key---2ecbb89d-1463-4669-a657-555f73b6fb1d, debtorIban=BE42063929068055, creditorIban=BE42063929068056, amount=100.0, communication=test), succeeded=false)
11:01:44,678 INFO  com.bnpp.pe.cep.Main                                          - SctRequestProcessStep3Event(super=SctRequestEvent(correlationId=cId---a14a4e23-56c5-4242-9c43-d465d2b84454, key=Key---f969dd4d-47ff-445c-9182-0f95a569febb, debtorIban=BE42063929068055, creditorIban=BE42063929068056, amount=100.0, communication=test), succeeded=false)
Right(SctRequestFinalEvent(super=SctRequestEvent(correlationId=cId---a14a4e23-56c5-4242-9c43-d465d2b84454, key=Key---2196fdb0-01e8-4cc6-af4b-04bcf9dc67a2, debtorIban=null, creditorIban=null, amount=null, communication=null), state=SUCCESS))
11:01:49,635 INFO  com.bnpp.pe.cep.Main                                          - Timed out events:
11:01:49,636 INFO  com.bnpp.pe.cep.Main                                          - SctRequestProcessStep3Event(super=SctRequestEvent(correlationId=cId---a14a4e23-56c5-4242-9c43-d465d2b84454, key=Key---f969dd4d-47ff-445c-9182-0f95a569febb, debtorIban=BE42063929068055, creditorIban=BE42063929068056, amount=100.0, communication=test), succeeded=false)
11:01:49,636 INFO  com.bnpp.pe.cep.Main                                          - SctRequestProcessStep2Event(super=SctRequestEvent(correlationId=cId---a14a4e23-56c5-4242-9c43-d465d2b84454, key=Key---0b3c116e-0703-43cb-8b3e-54b0b5e93948, debtorIban=BE42063929068055, creditorIban=BE42063929068056, amount=100.0, communication=test), succeeded=false)
11:01:49,636 INFO  com.bnpp.pe.cep.Main                                          - Timed out events:
11:01:49,636 INFO  com.bnpp.pe.cep.Main                                          - SctRequestProcessStep3Event(super=SctRequestEvent(correlationId=cId---a14a4e23-56c5-4242-9c43-d465d2b84454, key=Key---f969dd4d-47ff-445c-9182-0f95a569febb, debtorIban=BE42063929068055, creditorIban=BE42063929068056, amount=100.0, communication=test), succeeded=false)
Left(SctRequestFinalEvent(super=SctRequestEvent(correlationId=cId---a14a4e23-56c5-4242-9c43-d465d2b84454, key=Key---aa437bcf-ecaa-4561-9f4e-08a902f0e248, debtorIban=null, creditorIban=null, amount=null, communication=null), state=FAILED))
Left(SctRequestFinalEvent(super=SctRequestEvent(correlationId=cId---a14a4e23-56c5-4242-9c43-d465d2b84454, key=Key---5420eb41-2723-42ac-83fd-d203d6bf2526, debtorIban=null, creditorIban=null, amount=null, communication=null), state=FAILED))
```

My test code:

```
package com.bnpp.pe.cep;

import com.bnpp.pe.event.Event;
import com.bnpp.pe.event.SctRequestFinalEvent;
import com.bnpp.pe.util.EventHelper;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.functions.KeySelector;
import org.apache.flink.cep.CEP;
import org.apache.flink.cep.PatternSelectFunction;
import org.apache.flink.cep.PatternStream;
import org.apache.flink.cep.PatternTimeoutFunction;
import org.apache.flink.cep.pattern.Pattern;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.TimeCharacteristic;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.time.Time;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer010;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.util.serialization.DeserializationSchema;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;

/**
 * Created by Laurent Bauchau on 2/08/2017.
 */
@Slf4j
public class Main implements Serializable {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public static final String step1Topic = "sctinst-step1";
    public static final String step2Topic = "sctinst-step2";
    public static final String step3Topic = "sctinst-step3";

    private static final String PATTERN_NAME = "the_3_correlated_events_pattern";

    private final FlinkKafkaConsumer010<Event> kafkaSource1;
    private final DeserializationSchema<Event> deserializationSchema1;

    private final FlinkKafkaConsumer010<Event> kafkaSource2;
    private final DeserializationSchema<Event> deserializationSchema2;

    private final FlinkKafkaConsumer010<Event> kafkaSource3;
    private final DeserializationSchema<Event> deserializationSchema3;

    private Main() {

        // Kafka init
        Properties kafkaProperties = new Properties();
        kafkaProperties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        kafkaProperties.setProperty("zookeeper.connect", "localhost:2180");
        kafkaProperties.setProperty("group.id", "sct-validation-cgroup1");

        deserializationSchema1 = new SctRequestProcessStep1EventDeserializer();
        kafkaSource1 = new FlinkKafkaConsumer010<>(step1Topic, deserializationSchema1, kafkaProperties);

        deserializationSchema2 = new SctRequestProcessStep2EventDeserializer();
        kafkaSource2 = new FlinkKafkaConsumer010<>(step2Topic, deserializationSchema2, kafkaProperties);

        deserializationSchema3 = new SctRequestProcessStep3EventDeserializer();
        kafkaSource3 = new FlinkKafkaConsumer010<>(step3Topic, deserializationSchema3, kafkaProperties);

        try {
            StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
            env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.IngestionTime);

            DataStream<Event> s1 = env.addSource(kafkaSource1);
            DataStream<Event> s2 = env.addSource(kafkaSource2);
            DataStream<Event> s3 = env.addSource(kafkaSource3);

            DataStream<Event> unionStream = s1.union(s2, s3);

            Pattern successPattern = Pattern.<Event>begin(PATTERN_NAME)
                    .times(3)
                    .within(Time.seconds(5));

            PatternStream<Event> matchingStream = CEP.pattern(
                    unionStream.keyBy(new CIDKeySelector()),
                    successPattern);

            matchingStream.select(new MyPatternTimeoutFunction(), new MyPatternSelectFunction())
                    .print()
                    .setParallelism(1);

            env.execute();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    private static class MyPatternTimeoutFunction implements PatternTimeoutFunction<Event, SctRequestFinalEvent> {

        @Override
        public SctRequestFinalEvent timeout(Map<String, List<Event>> pattern, long timeoutTimestamp) throws Exception {

            List<Event> events = pattern.get(PATTERN_NAME);
            log.info("Timed out events:");
            events.forEach(e -> log.info(e.toString()));

            // Resulting event creation
            SctRequestFinalEvent event = new SctRequestFinalEvent();
            EventHelper.correlate(events.get(0), event);
            EventHelper.injectKey(event);
            event.setState(SctRequestFinalEvent.State.FAILED);

            return event;
        }
    }

    private static class MyPatternSelectFunction
            implements PatternSelectFunction<Event, SctRequestFinalEvent> {

        @Override
        public SctRequestFinalEvent select(Map<String, List<Event>> pattern) throws Exception {

            List<Event> events = pattern.get(PATTERN_NAME);
            log.info("Matching events:");
            events.forEach(e -> log.info(e.toString()));

            // Resulting event creation
            SctRequestFinalEvent event = new SctRequestFinalEvent();
            EventHelper.correlate(events.get(0), event);
            EventHelper.injectKey(event);
            event.setState(SctRequestFinalEvent.State.SUCCESS);

            return event;
        }
    }

    private static class CIDKeySelector implements KeySelector<Event, String> {
        @Override
        public String getKey(Event event) throws Exception {
            return event.getCorrelationId();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's analyze what does your pattern says. You are passing a pattern like:

```
Pattern.<Event>begin(PATTERN_NAME)
    .times(3)
    .within(Time.seconds(5));
```

It does say, search for sequence of three any events that occur within 5 seconds. Right now flink starts searching for new match each subsequent event (There is ongoing work to introduce new `MatchingBehaviours`see [FLINK-7169](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-7169)).

So to show simple example. If you have a sequence like `A B C D E` within 5 seconds. The CEP library will return results:

- A B C
- B C D
- C D E

and two timeouted:

- D E
- D

Comment: I understand your point but my pattern work on a KeyedStream that contains only 3 correlated Event at a time and never more, and I run my test by sending only 3 correlated Event in Kafka:

Just (A,B,C) and (A,B,C) matches and in this case I don't understand why I received (A,C) and (C) as timeouted partialy matched events?

Comment: understood! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Your program....**

In Your program **select**  the text  **by time** , So your passing the PatterStream object to BOTH Function.No need Time for select the string ...You don't go for PatternTimeOutFunction().

**See Here ,With out Time Factor.**

```
import org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple2;
import org.apache.flink.cep.CEP;
import org.apache.flink.cep.PatternSelectFunction;
import org.apache.flink.cep.PatternStream;
import org.apache.flink.cep.pattern.Pattern;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.time.Time;

import java.util.Map;

public class FlinkCEP {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // set up the execution environment
        final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        DataStream<String> text = env.socketTextStream("localhost", 1111)
                .flatMap(new LineTokenizer());

        text.print();

        Pattern<String, String> pattern =
                Pattern.<String>begin("start").where(txt -> txt.equals("a"))
                       .next("middle").where(txt -> txt.equals("b"))
                       .followedBy("end").where(txt -> txt.equals("c")).within(Time.seconds(1));

        PatternStream<String> patternStream = CEP.pattern(text, pattern);

        DataStream<String> alerts = patternStream.select(new PatternSelectFunction<String, String>() {
            @Override
            public String select(Map<String, String> matches) throws Exception {
                return "Found: " +
                        matches.get("start") + "->" +
                        matches.get("middle") + "->" +
                        matches.get("end");
            }
        });

        // emit result
        alerts.print();

        // execute program
        env.execute("WordCount Example");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks... but
1) I need the PatternTimeoutFunction to catch failed processing
2) I could use the other select signature(without PatternTimeoutFunction) if I don't need to catch failed processing
3) I cannot use static where clauses like txt.equals("a") because I need to compare events, that's why I use a KeyedStream